# What is "Name" in "IdentityType" (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, account-management

I want to search a user with "Display Name". I come across FindByIdentity function and it can search with below IdentityTypes:

> DistinguishedName 3    The identity is a Distinguished Name (DN).
>
> Guid  5    The identity is a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID).
>
> **Name    1    The identity is a name.**
>
> SamAccountName    0    The identity is a Security Account Manager (SAM)
>   name.
>
> Sid   4    The identity is a Security Identifier (SID) in Security
>   Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL) format.
>
> UserPrincipalName 2    The identity is a User Principal Name (UPN).

(refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype?view=netframework-4.7.2)

May I have your advice what is "Name" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Name field corresponds to the `CN` value (Common Name) for the object, which is unique within the domain.

Comment: Sorry may I ask is there any function to search an AD user with "Display Name"?

Comment: Hi @Mark. There is no direct defined method as such, but you can use LDAPSearchFilter for the attribute `displayName` like: (&(objectClass=user)(displayName=yourInputValue)).

Comment: Sure. Thanks. You_are_helpful.